# add Thunderbolt 3 connectivity to MSI X99S SLI Plus

Tags: motherboard, thunderbolt

I currently have an MSI X99S SLI Plus motherboard (5-6 years old) which I'd like to keep, but I'd like to add Thunderbolt 3 connectivity to my PC (mainly for connecting a modern low-latency audio interface).

1. How can this be achieved, if it's even possible at all?
2. If it is possible using an adapter/add-on card, what are the downsides compared to a motherboard with built-in TB3 connectivity?